# Repeat HTML element multiple times using ngFor based on an object property

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I am creating an object, `starStructure` based off each object's `vote_average`. This is what my object array looks like:

```
[
  {"title":"Solo: A Star Wars Story",
   "vote_average":7.1,
   "starStructure":{"full":3,
                    "halfStar":true
                   }
   },
  {"title":"Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom",
   "vote_average":6.5,
   "starStructure":{"full":3}
  }
]
```

How can I use `*ngFor` to repeat `<i class="material-icons">star</i>` for the amount of times listed in `starStructure.full`?

I have created a [StackBlitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzqzdd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return an array of size

```
arr(size: number) {
  return Array.from(Array(size), (_, i) => i);
}
```

and ngFor over it

```
<i class="material-icons" *ngFor="let i of arr(movie.starStructure.full)">
  star
</i>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4wwbh

Comment: Calling methods from the template is discouraged in Angular